# Integral non-zero only if integrand is to the power of two

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, concentration-of-measure

Is it possible to find a probability space $(\mathbb{C}, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex plane and $\Sigma$ is the Borel sigma algebra,  and a measurable function $F$ such that,

$$
\int_\mathbb{C} d \mathbb{P}(t) F^n(t) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \mbox{if $n \in \mathbb{N} \, \, : \, \, n \not\in \{0,2\}$} \\
\neq 0 ~& \mbox{if $n=2$}.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. One example goes as follows.

Take $F(t) \equiv t$, and let $\mathbb{P}$ be the probability measure on the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ given by
$$d \mathbb{P} (\theta)
= \frac{1 + \cos 2 \theta}{2 \pi} \, d\theta.$$

Note that using this measure, the integrals in question can be written as
$$\int d \mathbb{P} (t) \, F^n (t)
= \int d \mathbb{P} (t) \, t^n
= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{i n \theta} (1 + \cos 2 \theta) \, d\theta.$$

Using the orthogonality properties of $\{ \sin n \theta \}$ and $\{ \cos n \theta \}$ on $[0, 2\pi]$ then establishes the desired conditions.